# Running NERDTree upon opening a new tab in Vim

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I'm using the vim plugin NERDTree, and I have the following command in my vimrc file so that nerdtree automatically runs when I open vim:

au VimEnter *  NERDTree

However, when I create a new tab, I want NERDTreeMirror to run on the new tab (which, the command above isn't even running on new tabs so adding au VimEnter * NERDTreeMirror is ineffective).
Is there something I can set in the vimrc file to run *au VimEnter *  NERDTreeMirror* on new tabs when they're opened?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may take a look at all the autocmd events using `:help event`. There are several interesting events like `TabEnter` and `BufNew`.

By the way, it's more convenient for me to use <kbd>F3</kbd> to toggle NERDTree in the current tab:

```
autocmd VimEnter * nmap <F3> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
autocmd VimEnter * imap <F3> <Esc>:NERDTreeToggle<CR>a
let NERDTreeQuitOnOpen=1
let NERDTreeWinSize=35
```

Comment: This alternative is probably much better.  Thanks to TabEnter I was able to have NERDTree run on new tabs, but it calls NERDTree too soon. The tree pane and the file's pane will be swapped in both position and size.  Closing and reopening nerdtree fixes it after the fact.  I tried to call a function that swaps position and size on the tree and file panes, but it failed because the file's pane doesn't even seem to be loaded by the time TabEnter first fires.  Oh well, seems a bit more sensible to leave nerdtree off until you need it after all.  Otherwise it's a waste of screen space.

Comment: Why do you need to map only at `VimEnter` events and not directly in vimrc? And why don't you use `nore` here?

Comment: @ZyX, nore prevents recursion - that is, if I do "nnore i I" it will map i to the I 'function', whereas without it I can "nmap i I" and it maps i to the I 'keystroke' - if there is a remapping of I, it will be expanded also. But in this case, the keystrokes ":NERDTreeToggle<CR>" are pretty unlikely to be remapped.

Comment: @AustinHastings You don’t need the whole thing to be remapped. Remapping only `:` is enough. Before you say it is unlikely I will explain why it is the opposite: `:` is used more common then `;`, but requires shift to press. So some users do `noremap ; :` and `noremap : ;` and this will break your mapping. Also note that there is pretty common thing to remap `E` to `e` if it is the first character because it is common to fail to remove finger from shift when typing `:e`. For the same reason and with the similar command `N` at the start may be mapped to `n` if user uses `:next` often.

Comment: Thus you ***must not*** use non-nore version unless you have no other choice. Or adding any new mapping will become O(N) (N: total length of rhs of all mappings defined without `nore`) operation because you will have to review whether it’ll break something.